# file offsets on windows

Tags: windows, ms-access, scripting, file, offset

Is there an easy way, preferably with a scripting language or a small tool that could be called through a batch file, to operate on a text file, mark an offset, and put everything after the offset into a new file?

I have a text file added to nightly, and I would like to make it so that the end of the file is marked, then after new data is added, only data between the offset and the end is processed. I can not do this with just strings or delimiters as it is blob data.

edit: The text file is created by running a ms access macro from a scheduled tasks, which exports the data as a csv file. In considering Patricks suggestion, I would like to know if it would be possible to add a wildcard such as the date to the filename, to always have a different file. This file will then be scp'd to a linux server, where it will be loaded into a mysql database.

Comment: Can you timestamp the records in the file? Could you perhaps provide a brief example in your question of what you're dealing with?

Comment: It is the exported data of an access database, including some binary data. There is no date field and I cannot modify the access database to have one

Comment: I recommend editing your question to describe your process, and the Access database, and tag it with ms-access; you'll get better visibility and possibly more answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're currently exporting the data from the Access database with a script already:

```
@echo OFF

:: Force a new line and add a marker; assuming your file is data.txt.
@echo. >> data.txt
@echo **MARKER** >> data.txt

:: Run your export here: these lines just simulate the export.
@echo Test Line 1 >> data.txt
@echo Test Line 2 >> data.txt

:: Find line number of last marker:
for /f "usebackq delims=:" %%I in (`findstr /N "**MARKER**" data.txt`) do (
    set LAST_MARKER=%%I
)

:: Get all the lines after the last marker
for /f "skip=%LAST_MARKER% tokens=*" %%L in (data.txt) do (
    @echo %%L >> new_data.txt
)
```

The output in `new_data.txt` will be:

> Test Line 1
>   Test Line 2

Comment: I am using a macro within access that is run from the command line, would this be easy to do with a macro?

Comment: Your question asked "Is there an easy way, preferably with a scripting language or a small tool that could be called through a batch file"...

Comment: I have to ask; why not just put the data that would come after the marker into its own file?

Comment: That does seem obvious. I suppose because everything must run automatically each night.., I can set that up in linux, but can access have a wildcard or variable such as the date in the filename?

Comment: Not from a macro, but it can from VBA. If you already have a .BAT file that calls the Access macro from the command, then my solution should work for you.

Comment: You can also rename the file created by your .BAT file to have a timestamp: `for %I in (test.txt) do ren %I "%~nI_%DATE:~10,4%-%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%_%TIME:~0,2%-%TIME:~3,2%%~xI"`

Comment: Is that just a batch file for loop? I cannot get it to alter the filename at all.

Comment: If you're using this in a batch file use %%I instest if %I.

Comment: what about do ren? Should it be %%Ifor i in test if%I do ren?

Comment: Yes, use %%I everywhere %I is used. You use a single % on the command line, but double %%s within a batch script.

Comment: It should be:  `for %%I in (test.txt) do ren %%I "%%~nI_%DATE:~10,4%-%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%_%TIME:~0,2%-%TIME:~3,2%%%~xI"`

Comment: This produces test_-1.-00_14-53.txt for a computer set as the 19th November 2008. What does 1-00 correspond to?

Comment: That should be the date, as yyyy-mm-dd; If your local date format is different you'll have to change the substrings in the %DATE% parsing. From a command line, type `echo %DATE%`; for me it returns "Mon 02/02/2009", so the year starts in position 10 for a length of 4 (0-bases string).

Comment: The month starts in position 4 for a length of 2, the day starts in position 7 for a length of 2. Adjust these start positions to match your regional settings.

Comment: Is there a way to store the result in a variable as well, to specify that is should be the file copied?

Comment: Sure: `for %%I in (test.txt) do set MyNewFilename="%%~nI_%DATE:~10,4%-%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%_%TIME:~0,2%-%TIME:~3,2%%%~xI"`

Comment: Then you can rename like: `ren OldFile.txt %MyNewFilename%`

Comment: Actually, each new file created will still contain all the data from the old file, so I am planning to use a combination of markers and dates. How would you modify the above to place everything after the marker into a new file with the name of the date? It would have to be automatic, perhaps rename

Comment: :: Create new file name
for %%I in (data.txt) do set NewFile="%%~nI_%DATE:~10,4%-%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%_%TIME:~0,2%-%TIME:~3,2%%%~xI"

:: Get all the lines after the last marker
for /f "skip=%LAST_MARKER% tokens=*" %%L in (data.txt) do (
    @echo %%L >> %NewFile%
)

Comment: Ahh, the problem is that access does not append data to the file, it recreates the file. Keeping this in mind, is there still a solution?

Answer (score 2):

It is simple with python:

```
import sys

def divide_file(fname, mark):
    mark_found = 0
    f = file(fname, 'r')
    for line in f.readlines():
        if mark in line:
            mark_found = 1
        if mark_found:
            print line.rstrip()
    f.close()

divide_file(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

Usage & output example:

```
c:\tmp>divide_file.py divide_file.py close
        f.close()

divide_file(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, but python is not a possibility for this instance.

Answer (score 1):

I could think of *tail*, *bash* and other utilities from Unix-like systems. You could get those on Windows by minimally installing [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msys). Documentation and examples referring to these utilities are quite easy to find. And *bash* stuff is way stronger than Windows batch files. The script would look something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

PREV_SIZE=`du -b text_file`
write_something_to_file text_file
CURR_SIZE=`du -b text_file`
let NUM=$PREV_SIZE-$CURR_SIZE
tail -c $NUM > new_text_file
```